# PCIe link to NVMe drive downgrades to 2.5GT/s (PCIe 1.0) after writing data

Tags: ssd, pci-express, nvme

I put a MKNSSDPL2TB-D8 NVMe drive in a Lenovo Thinkpad E595 laptop. When checking the speeds with `dd`, I noticed that they are not very good. It turns out that after the test,
the link speed was changed from 8GT/s to 2.5GT/s.

After boot, `lspci -vv` output includes these two entries:

```
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 PCIe GPP Bridge [6:0] (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5124
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin ? routed to IRQ 26
    IOMMU group: 1
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled] [32-bit]
    Memory behind bridge: d0900000-d09fffff [size=1M] [32-bit]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled] [64-bit]
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR+ NoISA- VGA- VGA16- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [58] Express (v2) Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 512 bytes, PhantFunc 0
            ExtTag+ RBE+
        DevCtl: CorrErr+ NonFatalErr+ FatalErr+ UnsupReq+
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag+ PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
            MaxPayload 256 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 8GT/s, Width x8, ASPM L1, Exit Latency L1 <64us
            ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep+ BwNot+ ASPMOptComp+
        LnkCtl: ASPM L1 Enabled; RCB 64 bytes, Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 8GT/s, Width x4
            TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive+ BWMgmt+ ABWMgmt-
        SltCap: AttnBtn- PwrCtrl- MRL- AttnInd- PwrInd- HotPlug- Surprise-
            Slot #0, PowerLimit 0W; Interlock- NoCompl+
        SltCtl: Enable: AttnBtn- PwrFlt- MRL- PresDet- CmdCplt- HPIrq- LinkChg-
            Control: AttnInd Unknown, PwrInd Unknown, Power- Interlock-
        SltSta: Status: AttnBtn- PowerFlt- MRL- CmdCplt- PresDet+ Interlock-
            Changed: MRL- PresDet- LinkState+
        RootCap: CRSVisible+
        RootCtl: ErrCorrectable- ErrNon-Fatal- ErrFatal- PMEIntEna+ CRSVisible+
        RootSta: PME ReqID 0000, PMEStatus- PMEPending-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range ABCD, TimeoutDis+ NROPrPrP- LTR+
             10BitTagComp- 10BitTagReq- OBFF Not Supported, ExtFmt+ EETLPPrefix+, MaxEETLPPrefixes 1
             EmergencyPowerReduction Not Supported, EmergencyPowerReductionInit-
             FRS- LN System CLS Not Supported, TPHComp- ExtTPHComp- ARIFwd+
             AtomicOpsCap: Routing- 32bit+ 64bit+ 128bitCAS-
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 65ms to 210ms, TimeoutDis- LTR+ 10BitTagReq- OBFF Disabled, ARIFwd-
             AtomicOpsCtl: ReqEn- EgressBlck-
        LnkCap2: Supported Link Speeds: 2.5-8GT/s, Crosslink- Retimer- 2Retimers- DRS-
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 2.5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis+
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance Preset/De-emphasis: -6dB de-emphasis, 0dB preshoot
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -3.5dB, EqualizationComplete+ EqualizationPhase1+
             EqualizationPhase2+ EqualizationPhase3+ LinkEqualizationRequest-
             Retimer- 2Retimers- CrosslinkRes: unsupported
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 00000000fee00000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [c0] Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5124
    Capabilities: [c8] HyperTransport: MSI Mapping Enable+ Fixed+
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [150 v2] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, ECRCGenCap- ECRCGenEn- ECRCChkCap- ECRCChkEn-
            MultHdrRecCap- MultHdrRecEn- TLPPfxPres- HdrLogCap-
        HeaderLog: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
        RootCmd: CERptEn+ NFERptEn+ FERptEn+
        RootSta: CERcvd- MultCERcvd- UERcvd- MultUERcvd-
             FirstFatal- NonFatalMsg- FatalMsg- IntMsg 0
        ErrorSrc: ERR_COR: 0000 ERR_FATAL/NONFATAL: 0000
    Capabilities: [270 v1] Secondary PCI Express
        LnkCtl3: LnkEquIntrruptEn- PerformEqu-
        LaneErrStat: 0
    Capabilities: [2a0 v1] Access Control Services
        ACSCap: SrcValid+ TransBlk+ ReqRedir+ CmpltRedir+ UpstreamFwd+ EgressCtrl- DirectTrans+
        ACSCtl: SrcValid+ TransBlk- ReqRedir+ CmpltRedir+ UpstreamFwd+ EgressCtrl- DirectTrans-
    Capabilities: [370 v1] L1 PM Substates
        L1SubCap: PCI-PM_L1.2+ PCI-PM_L1.1+ ASPM_L1.2+ ASPM_L1.1+ L1_PM_Substates+
              PortCommonModeRestoreTime=0us PortTPowerOnTime=10us
        L1SubCtl1: PCI-PM_L1.2+ PCI-PM_L1.1+ ASPM_L1.2+ ASPM_L1.1+
               T_CommonMode=10us LTR1.2_Threshold=25600ns
        L1SubCtl2: T_PwrOn=10us
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
```

```
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Silicon Motion, Inc. SM2262/SM2262EN SSD Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
    Subsystem: Silicon Motion, Inc. SM2262/SM2262EN SSD Controller
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 52
    NUMA node: 0
    IOMMU group: 9
    Region 0: Memory at d0900000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable+ 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
        Masking: 00000000  Pending: 00000000
    Capabilities: [70] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s unlimited, L1 unlimited
            ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset+ SlotPowerLimit 0W
        DevCtl: CorrErr+ NonFatalErr+ FatalErr+ UnsupReq+
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop- FLReset-
            MaxPayload 256 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr+ NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 8GT/s, Width x4, ASPM L1, Exit Latency L1 <8us
            ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
        LnkCtl: ASPM L1 Enabled; RCB 64 bytes, Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM+ AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 8GT/s, Width x4
            TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range ABCD, TimeoutDis+ NROPrPrP- LTR+
             10BitTagComp- 10BitTagReq- OBFF Not Supported, ExtFmt- EETLPPrefix-
             EmergencyPowerReduction Not Supported, EmergencyPowerReductionInit-
             FRS- TPHComp- ExtTPHComp-
             AtomicOpsCap: 32bit- 64bit- 128bitCAS-
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis- LTR+ 10BitTagReq- OBFF Disabled,
             AtomicOpsCtl: ReqEn-
        LnkCap2: Supported Link Speeds: 2.5-8GT/s, Crosslink- Retimer- 2Retimers- DRS-
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 8GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance Preset/De-emphasis: -6dB de-emphasis, 0dB preshoot
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -3.5dB, EqualizationComplete+ EqualizationPhase1+
             EqualizationPhase2+ EqualizationPhase3+ LinkEqualizationRequest-
             Retimer- 2Retimers- CrosslinkRes: unsupported
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=16 Masked-
        Vector table: BAR=0 offset=00002000
        PBA: BAR=0 offset=00002100
    Capabilities: [100 v2] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, ECRCGenCap+ ECRCGenEn- ECRCChkCap+ ECRCChkEn-
            MultHdrRecCap- MultHdrRecEn- TLPPfxPres- HdrLogCap-
        HeaderLog: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    Capabilities: [158 v1] Secondary PCI Express
        LnkCtl3: LnkEquIntrruptEn- PerformEqu-
        LaneErrStat: 0
    Capabilities: [178 v1] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Max snoop latency: 1048576ns
        Max no snoop latency: 1048576ns
    Capabilities: [180 v1] L1 PM Substates
        L1SubCap: PCI-PM_L1.2+ PCI-PM_L1.1+ ASPM_L1.2+ ASPM_L1.1+ L1_PM_Substates+
              PortCommonModeRestoreTime=10us PortTPowerOnTime=10us
        L1SubCtl1: PCI-PM_L1.2+ PCI-PM_L1.1+ ASPM_L1.2+ ASPM_L1.1+
               T_CommonMode=0us LTR1.2_Threshold=25600ns
        L1SubCtl2: T_PwrOn=10us
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme
```

Writing some data with `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/nvme0n1p1 bs=1M count=1024 conv=fsync` is not very fast: `1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 2.37567 s, 452 MB/s`. `/dev/nvme0n1p` spans the whole disk and is aligned to 1MiB boundaries.

In `lspci -vv` output, entry `00:01.1` (PCIe GPP Bridge) now contains `LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x4` and entry `01:00.0` (SSD) now contains `LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s (downgraded), Width x4`. There are no other changes in the output of `lspci`. `dmesg` doesn’t show anything PCIe-related during or after the test. For the test, I’ve used Archboot (a live system based on Arch Linux which runs from RAM). The kernel version is `5.18.10`.

What could be the reason for the speed downgrade? How can I debug this problem?

Comment: Maybe the kernel’s PCI Express Advanced Error Reporting (AER) driver could help diagnose the problem. I do not have any experience with this driver though.